# What is the use of an AC Power Entry Module?

Tags: ac, plug

I found the following AC line outlet in an old box used in outdoors:

[image]

And could manage to find its [datasheet](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0551/0900766b805511b3.pdf).

But in what kind of circumstances or conditions is this filer used? I cannot see any transient suppressor in it.

Comment: The filter is used to prevent high-frequency signals, for example generated by a switched-mode power supply, to "escape" via this mains connection. Without such a filter EMI regulations could be violated. Often such a filter is (also) placed on the PCB of the power supply. It does suppress transients as transients contain high frequency signals, which will be filtered.

Comment: It actually has its schematic printed on it....

Comment: Can it prevent common mode noises coming from bad SMPSs?

Answer (score 1):

It's not specifically for protecting against transients.  Its purpose is to filter the mains, to block high frequencies from leaving an electronic device.  These are particularly appropriate for switched mode power supplies.  This is for electromagnetic compatibility (EMC).

The capacitors effectively short out high-frequencies, while the inductors block them from passing through.

Comment: What can happen if it weren't used at all? What would high frequencies danage if they were radiated or conducted?

Comment: No damage, just that if there is no filter at all, harmonics of the power supply's switching frequency will be radiated through the mains. That can disturb other equipment. The product might violate EMI/EMC regulations and selling it might be illegal. Note that the filter does not have to be in the mains socket like here, it can be located somewhere else in the supply as well.

Comment: Can the harmonics and cause of it come from the AC network grid something else than SMPS?

Comment: @doncarlos Pretty much anything that isn't a simple resistive load could introduce unwanted harmonics.  The filter will also provide some protection to the appliance from electromagnetic interference *from* other devices plugged in nearby.

Comment: @doncarlos, motors are another good example of nosy load.